# How to do proportional move only on selection?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

How to proportionally move only the given selection and place the sphere of influence at a given point as it was selected 1 single item (in my case te very top of the object)?

[image: selection]

Comment: Hello :). Invert your selection (Ctrl+I) and hide the vertices (H). Then after your proportional edit, simply unhide all vertices (Alt+H).

Comment: Hello! :) It's worked perfectly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three simple steps:

1. Invert your selection (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and hide the vertices (<kbd>H</kbd>)
2. Transform using proportional editing
3. Unhide all vertices, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I wish we had weightmap-based proportional _selection_ instead of proportional editing.

Answer (score 0):

Every selected vertex will be moved 100%, only the adjacent ones will be partially influenced, depending on how far away they are from closest selected vertex. 
You can exclude vertices that are not connected (click on the interpolation method and tick the according boxes). The only other way to not influence vertices is to hide them while you're modelling. Thats a tiny bit dangerous though.