# How to curve only a side of a box

Tags: subdivision-surface

I made this box that I need to have some curved sides, only the ones highlighted in red. Applying a subsurf modifier curves everything though, and I need the side tabs to remain sharp. What would be the best way to do this?[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do proportional move only on selection?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179974/how-to-do-proportional-move-only-on-selection)

Comment: I'll give it a try.